# Does Calabash supports Python?

Tags: python, automated-tests, calabash

I am a newbie to calabash and I wish to write the calabash step definitions in python. 
Does calabash supports Python?
If yes, Please share the links/Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Calabash client for python.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No, Calabash requires ruby >= 2.0.

More details are on https://github.com/calabash/install